# Error pipeline step "serverless deploy" says "IamRoleLambdaExecution - Maximum policy size of 10240 bytes exceeded for role XXXXX"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

When I'm trying to push my new API to the AWS  using Bitbucket the Pipeline fails in the *serverless deploy* step and says:

*IamRoleLambdaExecution - Maximum policy size of 10240 bytes exceeded for role XXXXXX*

The last sucessfully created role XXXXXX has the following content:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:eu-central-1:123456789012:log-group:/aws/lambda/functionname1:*“,
                 …
                "arn:aws:logs:eu-central-1:123456789012:log-group:/aws/lambda/functionname50:*“           
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:eu-central-1:123456789012:log-group:/aws/lambda/functionname1:*“,
                 …
                "arn:aws:logs:eu-central-1:123456789012:log-group:/aws/lambda/functionname50:*“           
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I strip away every linefeed and space I get a little less than 10240 letters and signs. So I'm pretty sure that the big number of log permission in my role is my problem.

When I remove one of my functions it works and the API get's deployed. When I add one further function it shows the same error again.

I'm using the following plugins: serverless-plugin-browserify, serverless-offline, serverless-domain-manager, serverless-plugin-split-stacks, serverless-openapi-documentation

I'm searching a solution and trying things for nearly a week now. Does anyone know how I can get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [serverless-simplify-default-exec-role-plugin](https://github.com/shelfio/serverless-simplify-default-exec-role-plugin) plugin.

Install it from NPM and add it to your `serverless.yml` file:

```yaml
plugins:
  - '@shelf/serverless-simplify-default-exec-role-plugin'
```

---

This happens because the Serverless framework generates a very verbose and explicit IAM policy for CloudWatch access.

This plugins works by simplifying dozens of resources like :

```
"arn:${AWS::Partition}:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/production-users-createUser:*"
```

with 1 wildcard resource like:

```
"arn:${AWS::Partition}:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. It is a plugin called serverless-plugin-custom-roles that splits the one big IAM role for the service in several small services, one for each function.

The plugin can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-custom-roles

And thank you to Maycon Viana Bordin for his article that pointed me to the solution and explained the problem: https://medium.com/@mayconbordin/lessons-learned-building-a-large-serverless-project-on-aws-74d40f5b0b46

Answer (score 0):

**As a quick fix** I removed one function the deployment went successful.

Inspired by [this](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2508#issuecomment-355299860)

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful: https://github.com/shelfio/serverless-simplify-default-exec-role-plugin

I experienced an issue working with https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-custom-roles.  I think the issue I saw was because serverless-plugin-custom-roles did not seem to pickup the correct aws partition for AWS GovCloud and continued to reference the aws commercial partition.